# powershell to get sql server memory counters and show value

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am writing a powershell script to capture the following SQL server counters:

> SQL Server: Memory Manager: Total Server Memory (KB)
>
> SQL Server: Memory Manager: Target Server Memory (KB)

My machine has 3 instances of SQL servers, so I want this script to capture all counters dynamically and report the value for 1 sample only. i tried writing the following:

```
Get-counter -List *SQL*Memory* | Select paths, counter | format-list # doesn't display full list

Get-counter -List *SQL*Memory* | Select paths, counter | where {_.counter -like "*server memory*"} |format-list # displays nothing
```

eventually I want to run this across multiple servers with `-computername` parameter and hence I want it to capture dynamically.

Can anyone please help me in finding what is missing?
Following is the exact script that I am running:

```
Function checkTransactionsPerSecond([string] $Hostname )
{ 
    (Get-Counter -ListSet "*Databases").Counter | Where {$_ -like "*\Transactions/sec"} #this returns nothing
#   $listofmetrics = (Get-Counter -ListSet "*Databases").Counter | Where {$_ -like "*\Transactions/sec"}
#   $listofmetrics | Get-Counter
}

clear

    
foreach ($Hostname in Get-Content "D:\TEMP\machines.txt")
{
    Write-Host $Hostname
    checkTransactionsPerSecond($Hostname) 
}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Aaron Bertrand wrote a good post on it that is pretty detailed...[How I use PowerShell to collect Performance Counter data](https://sqlblog.org/2011/01/31/how-i-use-powershell-to-collect-performance-counter-data).

Then Laerte Junior has an excelent walk through on how he finds the counters he wants in a Simple-Talk article: [Gathering Perfmon Data with Powershell](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/gathering-perfmon-data-with-powershell/). This might be where you want to start. It has some cmdlets that he uses to capture the counters for a particular instance I believe.

See if this is what you  need:

```
$listofmetrics = (Get-Counter -ListSet "*Databases" -ComputerName $hostname).Counter | Where {$_ -like "*\Transactions/sec"}
$listofmetrics | Get-Counter
```

Comment: thanks for this...
But the main problem I am having is adding additional filters to the counters e.g. If I run the following:
$listOfMetrices=(Get-Counter -ListSet "*Databases" -ComputerName $Hostname |  where {$_.paths -like "*\transactions/sec"} )
$listOfMetrices | get-counter It shows me all counters under database category...but what I really want to see is transactions/sec for each database. Please help

Comment: adjusted answer.

Comment: Thanks Shawn, I tried using the code you updated. but, it is not able to find any counters now. (Get-Counter -ListSet "*Databases").Counter | Where {$_ -like "*\Transactions/sec"}
doesn't find any counter. thanks for your time

Comment: really? What version of SQL Server are  you working with? I only tried this on a Window Server 2008 R2, SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: I also just tried on my Window Server 2003, SQL 2005 and it returns a single counter of: \SQLServer:Databases(*)\Transactions/sec

Comment: I am running it on around 20 servers, windows 2003 and windows 2008, SQl 2000, SQL 2005 and SQL 2008. It is not even getting the counter locally :-(

Comment: Are they all on PowerShell v2.0? I don't know that it would work on SQL 2000 but I really don't see why it would not work on the other editions.

Comment: I am running this from a central management server using powerGUI (which is on 2.0). I have updated my question for the exact script I am running

Comment: I left out the -ComputerName on mine. Updated to include it. Your function is missing that as well. If you include that does it work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
$listofmetrics = Get-Counter -ListSet "*Databases" | Get-Counter -MaxSamples 1 | Select -ExpandProperty CounterSamples | Where {$_.path -like "\Transactions/sec"} | Select Path, CookedValue
```

This will output a list of databases and their associated \Transactions/sec. I'm getting errors on my side at the beginning of the search but I assume it's a permissions issue. Otherwise it works like a beauty. You could use Regex to clean it up if you like :)